# php_printer.dll or some other way to print to network printer

Tags: php, printing

What i'm trying to achieve is invoke a printer to print a file or something when it is generated. The printer is going to be on the same network.

I did some research and found `php_printer.dll` as a solution.
I'm currently running `PHP Version 5.4.25` on my server. I tried to find the required file but the links are all not working. I found a `php_printer.dll` from an unofficial site and when i tried to install it i got

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: printer: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20060613\nPHP    compiled with module API=20100525\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0`

So either if someone has the file or a solution for this problem (i'm guessing the file is outdated that's why it's conflicting with some other extension).

I'm also open to other alternatives as to print directly to the printer without the user having to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the correct file and installed it just fine.

Hope it might help someone else

[LINK](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/)